# Update default compute service account permission in google cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql, service-accounts

default service account does not have access to cloud sql and has only read only access to storage.
I tried adding cloud sql admin and storage admin permission to defautl service account but that does not seems to work.
I know it can be solved by using another service account that have these permission and using that when creating compute instance.
I am just curious to know why updating permission of default compute does not work?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that updating the permissions on the Compute Engine default service account is not enough to set the correct level of access you are trying to give to your Compute Engine instance, since, as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts#service_account_permissions):

> When you set up an instance to run as a service account, **the level of access the service account has is determined by the combination of access scopes granted to the instance and IAM roles granted to the service account**.

From my understanding you are only granting IAM roles to the service account, so, in order to give the desired access level, you should also update the Access scopes for your Compute Engine instance.

When you create a new Compute Engine instance, under Access scopes, it is selected "Allow default access" by default as you can see here [New instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KaIp.png). This default access has Cloud SQL access disabled and Cloud Storage access as read-only.

You can refer to [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances#changeserviceaccountandscopes) which explains how to change the access scopes for a Compute Engine instance:

> To change an instance's service account and access scopes, the instance must be temporarily stopped. To stop your instance, read the documentation for [Stopping an instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/stopping-or-deleting-an-instance). After changing the service account or access scopes, remember to [restart the instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/restarting-an-instance#restarting_a_stopped_instance).

Once you stop your instance, you can change the Access scopes to either "Set access for each API" or to "Allow full access to all Cloud APIs".

If you choose to set access for each API, you will have to search for "Cloud SQL" and then select "Enabled" and also for "Storage" and select the desired option (Read Only, Write Only, Read Write, Full)

For more information on Access Scopes please refer to [this doc](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts#service_account_permissions) and for more information on running Compute Engine instances as service account (including the default service account) please see [this doc](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts#compute_engine_default_service_account).

Comment: the default service account is not an instance service account: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts

Answer (score 0):

In the [Cloud IAM Admin](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam) you have to select your `Default Service Account` by hitting on that pen to the right; then a side.bar will pop up, where you can assign the following roles: `Cloud SQL Admin`, `Cloud SQL Client`, `Cloud SQL Editor`, `Cloud SQL Viewer`. it's the default role is `Editor`.

Comment: The compute machine default service account is 55749287011-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com. and and updated this service account permission to cloud sql admin. but when I run the cloud proxy , it gave me "default Compute Engine service account is not configured with sufficient permissions to clud sql"

Comment: I am now just confused between api access scope with service account user role permission. giving cloud sql permission to service account does not gives it permission to access cloud-sql ?

Comment: guess I have to correct myself: you need to create a new GCE instance - with the `Cloud SQL Admin` role already enabled, at creation time... or create a new instance service account and then use this one, instead.